# Two GitHub accounts on the same computer

Tags: github, ssh

First of all I know that this question has been asked and answered several times, but all solutions that I've found don't work.

Task is very simple - I have two GitHub accounts, one personal and second for business.

I tried to use a few configurations, but all were like this:

```
Host github.com-personal
    HostName github.com
    User kagarlickij
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_kagarlickij_private

Host github.com-business
    HostName github.com
    User dmytriy-kagarlickij
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_dmytriy-kagarlickij-business_private
```

... and it doesn't work. It works only if Host is github.com . Not github.com-business , not business.github.com , etc

Any ideas how to manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User` for ssh (push/pull) access is always "git", not your username.

Edit: Also, you must use the ssh alias from your config in the clone url:

> git clone github.com-personal:kagarlickij/terraform-aws-vm.git

If you do that ssh uses the hostname, user and identify from the corresponding config file section.

Comment: I've changed user to "git" for both personal and business parts of config but result is the same - I could clone repo only when Host is github.com

Comment: Updated answer.