# Problem with ssh and two Github accounts on the same machie

Tags: git, github, ssh

I want to use 2 GitHub accounts on a single machine with ssh - my work account and my personal account. I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.1.

For this purpose, for my private account:

1. I've generated a new SSH key (with ssh-keygen)
2. I've added the public key form 1) to my personal account in GitHub, under `Settings > SSH and GPG keys`
3. I've added both of my keys into `~/.ssh/config`, e.g.

```
    Host *
      AddKeysToAgent yes
      UseKeychain yes
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    Host *
      AddKeysToAgent yes
      UseKeychain yes
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_privgithub
```

Here I'm not sure if I have to use asterisk in the host portion or some alias as pointed out into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666016/two-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer). I also tried to use alias in the clone URL but it didn't work well. I can see the keys checksums when I run `ssh-add -l`. `id_rsa` is my work account key, the `id_rsa_privgithub` is my private key.

4. I've configured my private cloned repo correctly by `git config user.name 'my_personal_github_user'` and `git config user.email 'my_personal_github_email'`.

The problem is that with this configuration only my work account works. If I change the config to:

```
  Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_privgithub
```

then of course only my personal account works (e.g. I can push changes). How can I use both accounts without changing the config file all the time? Do I need to setup aliases and how can I use them (I know that for ssh push/pull git is always the user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HOST *` means, use the next lines for ALL hosts.
So your config files activates all lines, but for the most options only the first one is used.

The `HOST *` is used for options you really want to use for ALL hosts.

In your case you could work with aliases, like

```
HOST private_git
  hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_privgithub

HOST work_git github.com
  hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then you can use

```
git clone git@github.com:yourworkname/your-work-repo.git
git clone git@private_git:yourprivname/your-private-repo.git
```

Comment: Works like this but it seems very cumbersome.... :( Thank you!