# How to use two GitHub accounts on the same computer using two users in windows?

Tags: windows, git, github

I am using **two users in my windows pc** and **both the users need git** while they have different accounts on **GitHub**. so how can I fix this? is there a way that both of us can use two accounts on the same pc

I tried to do **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666016/two-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)** where they changed the **configuration file** but **my new user doesn't have the file**

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are two different account on your PC, they have each their `%USERPROFILE%`/`$HOME`.

That means each one can create their own SSH key (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""`) and register the `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` to their respective GitHub profile.
No need for a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` in that case.

---

If you have only one logged on user on your PC, but need to push as two different users, then yes:

- create two different key pairs (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f key1` and `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f key2`, in a created `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`)
- create a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` as you have seen.